# React-Native 302 redirect in webview

Tags: ssl, webview, oauth-2.0, react-native, redirect

Having Trouble getting react-native oauth2 login flow working in react native. I have a ssl server on heroku handling the server auth, and the auth flow works in the browser. However, in react-native webview, I figured it would follow the redirect automatically. Instead I get this issue [an ssl error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1fS4.png)

Is there something im missing? Can't find anything online to help with this issue.

I just have a simple webview implementation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class SfLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     uri: 'https://testendpoint/shouldredirectwhenhit'
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        source={{uri: this.state.uri}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have I would say the same issue but only on Android. I noticed not all redirects have this problem and I think the difference is in the response headers. Might have to do with the following headers Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Set-Cookie. I need to do more research.